# No suitable JDBC Driver when attempting to connect to Docker Postgres DB

Tags: java, postgresql, docker

I am working on a to-do list using a Java server and Postgres DB - specifically trying to set up a local dev environment using Docker Compose. The server has previously been deployed to Heroku and the database connection works without trouble. I am getting a `suitable driver not found error` when attempting to establish a connection between the server and DB in Docker.

The Java DB connection code:

```
    public void connectToDatabase() {
        try {
            String url = System.getenv("JDBC_DATABASE_URL");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            System.out.println("Database Connection Successful");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The Java Server Dockerfile:

```
FROM gradle:7.4-jdk17-alpine
ADD --chown=gradle . /code
WORKDIR /code
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["gradle", "--stacktrace", "run"]
```

The image builds without problems. However, when starting with `docker compose up`, I get the following error: `java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for "jdbc:postgresql://tasks-db:5432/test-tasks-db?user=postgres&password=postgres"`

The server still runs, just without the DB connection - I can access other endpoints/features.

Docker Compose:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  java-service:
    build: 
      context: ./EchoServer/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    environment:
      - PORT=5000
      - JDBC_DATABASE_URL="jdbc:postgresql://tasks-db:5432/test-tasks-db?user=postgres&password=postgres"
  tasks-db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "1235:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    volumes: 
      - tasks-db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
  tasks-db:
    driver: local
  logvolume01: {}
```

Grateful for any help, have been blocked on this most of the evening.

EDIT: build.gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.0'
    implementation 'org.json:json:20210307'
    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.3.1'
}
```

Comment: I hope you aren't really using the superuser account `postgres` inside your application to connect to the database. That's a really bad idea.

Comment: Just for testing purposes - I want to make sure everything can communicate.

Answer (score 4):

So after a lot of trial and error, it was a problem with the docker-compose yml, specifically the environmental variable for the DB.

BAD:
`JDBC_DATABASE_URL="jdbc:postgresql://tasks-db:5432/test-tasks-db?user=postgres&password=postgres"`

This gives DriverManager the url wrapped in quotes. You do not want this.

GOOD:
`JDBC_DATABASE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://tasks-db:5432/test-tasks-db?user=postgres&password=postgres`

Lack of quotation marks in docker-compose.yml leads to a happy DriverManager.

Comment: I dont know why, but it helped, thanks!

Comment: This is a nasty gotcha which I just discovered running a container directly (no docker-compose) with the `--env-file` option to pass URLs and credentials.

The distinction is that while these look like normal shell variables, Docker does not do any interpolation that a shell does and so interprets quotes as literal characters in the "environment" values.

Answer (score 1):

You don't show how you build your Java application - but you're missing a dependency on the postgres JDBC driver.  It does not come with Java, but has to be presented to a Java application in its classpath.  Using maven, you would add this dependency: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql/42.3.3

Comment: Heres the relevant part of build.gradle file - my understanding is that JDBC driver is the last dependency:
 
```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.0'
    implementation 'org.json:json:20210307'
    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.3.1'
}
```